# Change Emacs Mode-Line color based on major-mode

Tags: emacs, elisp, emacs-faces, modeline

I like to see if there is a way to change the mode-link foreground and background color base on the major-mode,

I was thinking to add the logic in the

```
(add-hook 'after-change-major-mode-hook
```

But, I do not have all the emacs lisp experience to make such change.  Here is the logic:

```
switch major-mode:
case "emacs-lisp-mode":
  (set-face-foreground 'mode-line "ivory")
  (set-face-background 'mode-line "DarkOrange2")
case "ruby-mode":
  (set-face-foreground 'mode-line "white")
  (set-face-background 'mode-line "red")
...
default:
  (set-face-foreground 'mode-line "black")
  (set-face-background 'mode-line "white")
end switch
```

Many thanks in advance!.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You probably want something like:

```
(add-hook 'emacs-lisp-mode-hook
          (lambda ()
            (face-remap-add-relative
             'mode-line '((:foreground "ivory" :background "DarkOrange2") mode-line))))
```

You might want to use face-remap for the `mode-line-inactive` face as well.

Comment: THANK YOU VERY MUCH. This works beautifully :) Would you also be kind to help me combine your add-hook by using a predefined list? Similar to "sds" suggestion but add-hook to all the mode in the predefined list with the colors?  Thanks!

Comment: You mean like `(dolist (x '((emacs-lisp-mode :foreground "ivory" :background "DarkOrange2") (ruby-mode :foreground "white" :background "red"))) (add-hook (intern (concat (symbol-name (car x)) "-mode")) (lambda () (face-remap-add-relative 'mode-line (cons (cdr x) '(mode-line))))))` tho beware that it will only work in a `lexical-binding:t` buffer.

Comment: I have tried something like: `(add-hook 'shell-mode-hook
          (lambda ()
            (font-lock-variable-name-face
             'mode-line '((:foreground "LightGoldenrod" :weight bold) mode-line))))
` which didn't have any affect :-(

Answer (score 3):

"The logic" you are talking about is something like this:

```
(add-hook 'after-change-major-mode-hook 'my-set-mode-line-colors)
(defvar my-mode-line-colors
  '((emacs-lisp-mode :foreground "ivory" :background "DarkOrange2")
    (ruby-mode :foreground "white" :background "red")))
(defun my-set-mode-line-colors ()
  (face-remap-add-relative
   'mode-line (list (or (cdr (assq major-mode my-mode-line-colors))
                        '(:foreground "black" :background "white"))
                    'mode-line)))
```

Alternatively, you can do that from mode-specific hooks, as suggested by Stefan.

Comment: I actually had the add-hook to each mode.  But when I switch buffer from ruby to lisp, etc., the mode-line did not get update.. Hence I thought about "change-major-mode-hook" and you are right, neither work either...  is that a buffer-switch-hook ?  I tried to look for something like it but no avail.  Thanks!

Comment: The problem, as I wrote, is that the emacs faces are not buffer-local, so the above set-face-foreground calls will affect all windows and all mode lines. The is no way to make mode-line appearance buffer-specific

Comment: the set-face-foreground can be set per frame.  even if I have multiple frames up, I can change the mode-line just for that frame... as long as I could tell when a buffer is switched in and out and change the mode-line, it should work..

Comment: if you have one frame per buffer, yes, you should be fine. I have a single maximized frame, so this is not a method for me.